# Meteor 1.4.2.3 - babel-runtime npm package could not be found in your node_modules

Tags: meteor, babeljs

I've just deployed a Meteor app on an Ubuntu server, installed all packages but when I try to access the page, browser console keep showing me this

```
Uncaught Error: The babel-runtime npm package could not be found in your node_modules 
directory. Please run the following command to install it:

  meteor npm install --save babel-runtime


    at t.node_modules.meteor.babel-runtime.babel-runtime.js (a72cdf7….js?meteor_js_resource=true:34)
    at a (a72cdf7….js?meteor_js_resource=true:9)
    at r (a72cdf7….js?meteor_js_resource=true:9)
    at a72cdf7….js?meteor_js_resource=true:34
    at a72cdf7….js?meteor_js_resource=true:34
t.node_modules.meteor.babel-runtime.babel-runtime.js @ a72cdf7….js?meteor_js_resource=true:34
a @ a72cdf7….js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
r @ a72cdf7….js?meteor_js_resource=true:9
(anonymous) @ a72cdf7….js?meteor_js_resource=true:34
(anonymous) @ a72cdf7….js?meteor_js_resource=true:34
```

I executed meteor npm install --save babel-runtime as asked but it appears to have no effect.

Anybody facing this same error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are running Meteor commands on your server you are doing it wrong. You should build a bundle, deploy the bundle, do an npm install and be ready to go

Comment: Well that's what I'm doing, and still getting this error on client.

Comment: Hi yes I am having this trouble as well...were you able to solve this? how?

Answer (score 0):

Note that this error is from 2017. Several people were helped back then by [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8032#issuecomment-271160555):

> Be sure that you npm install before building your production bundle.
>
> ```
> $ git clone repo
> $ cd repo
> $ npm install # IMPORTANT!
> $ meteor build --directory ../build
> ```

Nowadays on Meteor 1.8.1, I'm getting the same error, except with `@babel/runtime` instead of `babel-runtime`. And the same solution still works: run `npm install` in your source directory *before* running `meteor build`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with a Meteor app, turned out that the package.json was not correctly formatted which prevented the npm install step from running properly during the build.

In our case the version set for the app in the package.json didn't follow the semantic rules for node versioning (can't contain letters which ours did.)